# Using filters to count values in Kibana / Visualize?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

(I am quite new to ELK stack and may ask something obvious...)

I have documents describing customers informations, with data such as name, address, age, etc...
Sometimes, not all these fields exist and I would like to know the number of documents having them filled.

If the data looks like:

```
PUT customers
{
  "mappings": {
    "customer": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "category": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "email": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "age": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "address": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"customers","_type":"customer"}}
{"id":"1","category":"aa","email":"sam@test.com"}
{"index":{"_index":"customers","_type":"customer"}}
{"id": "2", "category" : "aa", "age": "5"}
{"index":{"_index":"customers","_type":"customer"}}
{"id": "3", "category" : "aa", "email": "bob@test.com", "age": "36"}
{"index":{"_index":"customers","_type":"customer"}}
{"id": "4", "category" : "bb", "email": "kim@test.com", "age": "42", "address": "london"}
```

The idea is to have in **Kibana visualize** a data table like :

```
+----------+-------+-------+-----+---------+
| category | total | email | age | address |
+----------+-------+-------+-----+---------+
| aa       |     3 |     2 |   2 |       0 |
| bb       |     1 |     1 |   1 |       1 |
+----------+-------+-------+-----+---------+
```

(eg: we have 3 customers in category "aa"; among them 2 gave their email, 2 gave their age, none gave its address)

I can figure out how to do that with a query like:

```
POST /customers/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "category": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count_email": {
          "filter": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "email"
            }
          }
        },
        "count_age": {
          "filter": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "age"
            }
          }
        },
        "count_address": {
          "filter": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "address"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I can't find how we can do that in Kibana Visualize.
Should I use scripted fields ? JSON inputs ? how ? is there a better way ?

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: This doesn't give you the proper table? What are the results?

Comment: I updated my answer to include a starting url for kibana... is this closer to what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

In the UI I was able to split the rows using the keyword term filter.

Below is a url to get you started.

The call will create a data table, aggregate by count and split rows by category keyword term.

```
http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/visualize/create?type=table&indexPattern=customers&_g=()&_a=(filters:!(),linked:!f,query:(query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:'*')),uiState:(vis:(params:(sort:(columnIndex:!n,direction:!n)))),vis:(aggs:!((enabled:!t,id:'1',params:(),schema:metric,type:count),(enabled:!t,id:'2',params:(field:category.keyword,order:desc,orderBy:_term,size:2),schema:bucket,type:terms)),listeners:(),params:(perPage:10,showMeticsAtAllLevels:!f,showPartialRows:!f,showTotal:!f,sort:(columnIndex:!n,direction:!n),totalFunc:sum),title:'CategoryTable',type:table))
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Just to avoid misunderstanding, I updated the question with the index description. Where there is actually no array data type (which seems to be the situation where `nested` type is usefull ?).

Comment: I see that now... with the change I don't see anything wrong with your code. What result are you getting? Give me a few minutes to install the stack and ill setup your scenario

Comment: the search query I put in the question gives the expected results, but my question is to be able to reproduce that in Kibana / Visualize.

Comment: I was playing around with the visualizer using your dataset. It seems like you want to use a split rows .. im not sure how that looks in json but it will segment your data correctly based on the category.keyword

Comment: Segmenting data per category to get the number of documents is OK. The problem is to get the totals for documents with emal not null, age not null, address not null (see table example in the question).